# Faster alternative for numpy einsum in Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, tensordot, einsum

I am trying to perform the following operations on some tensors. Currently I am using einsum, and I wonder if there is a way (maybe using dot or tensordot) to make things faster, since I feel like what I am doing is more or less some outer and inner products.

Scenario 1:

```
A = np.arange(6).reshape((2, 3))
B = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 3, 2))
res1 = numpy.einsum('ij, kjh->ikjh', A, B)

>>> res1 = 
[[[[ 0  0]
   [ 2  3]
   [ 8 10]]

  [[ 0  0]
   [ 8  9]
   [20 22]]]


 [[[ 0  3]
   [ 8 12]
   [20 25]]

  [[18 21]
   [32 36]
   [50 55]]]].
```

Scenario 2:

```
C = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 3, 2))
D = np.arange(6).reshape((3, 2))
res2 = np.einsum('ijk, jk->ij', C, D)

>>> res2 = 
[[ 1 13 41]
 [ 7 43 95]]
```

I have tried using tensordot and dot, and for some reason, I cannot figure the right way to set the axes...

Comment: Generally `einsum` performs well.  Where relevant it's converted to a `matmul` calculation.  `tensordot` is not special.  It just reshapes and transposes to reduce the task to a `dot`.  I don't see a sum-of-products in your first line, so that should be expressible as a broadcasted product.  The second does have `k` as sum-of-products, so might be a `matmul`.  Give us a [mcve] so it will be easier to test and demonstate alternatives.

Comment: optimize the path ie `np.einsum_path(path, optimize = 'optimal')` then use the optimized path within `np.eisum`

Comment: Alternatively, for a single call, `optimize=True` is often enough (faster planification and a bit slower execution). The default is `optimize=False` which is only good for small arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the reminder. Added the MWE, first time posting on the Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explore your first calculation.  I'll start with a small example, to make sure values match. Timings on this size may not reflect your real-world needs.

```
In [138]: n,m,k = 2,3,4
In [141]: A = np.arange(n*m).reshape(n,m)
In [142]: B = np.arange(n*m*k).reshape(n,m,k)


In [144]: res1 = np.einsum('ij, kjh->ikjh', A, B)    
In [145]: res1.shape
Out[145]: (2, 2, 3, 4)
```

Since there's no sum-of-products (`j` is in all terms), we can do it with broadcasted multiply:

```
In [146]: x=A[:,None,:,None]*B
In [147]: x.shape
Out[147]: (2, 2, 3, 4)
```

And the results and shapes match:

```
In [148]: np.allclose(res1,x)
Out[148]: True
```

Some times (with the usual scalar qualification):

```
In [149]: timeit res1 = np.einsum('ij, kjh->ikjh', A, B)
13.6 µs ± 67.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [150]: timeit x=A[:,None,:,None]*B
7.2 µs ± 74.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [151]: timeit res1 = np.einsum('ij, kjh->ikjh', A, B, optimize=True)
90.5 µs ± 2.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The broadcasted result is best - I expect that to hold for larger arrays.  And the `optimize` does not help.  We could look at the `einsum_path`, but with only 2 arguments, there's isn't much to improve on.

### 2nd

```
In [152]: C = np.arange(n*m*k).reshape(n,m,k)
D = np.arange(m*k).reshape(m,k)

In [153]: res2 = np.einsum('ijk, jk->ij', C, D)
In [154]: res2.shape
Out[154]: (2, 3)
```

These shape broadcast without change:

```
In [155]: (C*D).shape
Out[155]: (2, 3, 4)    
In [156]: y=(C*D).sum(2)  # sum-of-products on last dimension    
In [157]: y.shape
Out[157]: (2, 3)
```

which matches the einsum:

```
In [158]: np.allclose(res2,y)
Out[158]: True
```

A matmul approach:

```
In [159]: (C@D.T).shape
Out[159]: (2, 3, 3)    
In [160]: np.allclose((C@D.T)[:,np.arange(3),np.arange(3)],res2)
Out[160]: True
```

I don't like having to take the last diagonal; I'll have to play with it some more.

For these small timings, `einsum` is still best:

```
In [164]: timeit res2 = np.einsum('ijk, jk->ij', C, D)
11.9 µs ± 31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [165]: timeit y=(C*D).sum(2)
13.9 µs ± 25.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [166]: timeit (C@D.T)[:,np.arange(3),np.arange(3)]
21.4 µs ± 78.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

### 2nd matmul

The correct, and faster matmul

```
In [167]: (C[:,:,None,:]@D[:,:,None]).shape
Out[167]: (2, 3, 1, 1)
```

squeeze out the trailing 1s:

```
In [168]: np.allclose((C[:,:,None,:]@D[:,:,None])[:,:,0,0],res2)
Out[168]: True

In [169]: timeit (C[:,:,None,:]@D[:,:,None])
6.63 µs ± 24.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

I could probably use a similar trick to perform the first example with matmul, with sum-of-products on a dummy size 1 dimension.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. I will take that matmul for first scenario as an exercise for myself. Thanks again!